# Javascript equality operators

Tags: javascript, equality

In David Flanagan's Javascript guide, there is a statement:

> the == operator never attempts to convert its operands to boolean

So here I did a little test:

```
var a = false;
var b = ""; // empty string
a == b; //returns true
```

Looking at [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) there is a point:

> e. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false. Otherwise, return false.

How can x and y be both true if y is string data type (without conversion)?

Comment: "If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y." followed by "If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String,
return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y)."

Comment: Related: http://algorithmicassertions.com/visualization/2014/03/27/Better-JS-Equality-Table.html and http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens under the hood is

> If `Type(x)` is `Boolean`, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.

```
Number(false) == ""
```

followed by

> If `Type(x)` is `Number` and `Type(y)` is `String`, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.

```
Number(false) == Number("") -> 0 == 0
```

> How can x and y be both true if y is string data type (without conversion)?

They are not both `true`, but after type coercion their values are equal.

> the == operator never attempts to convert its operands to boolean

And that is correct, if you check the comparison algorithm you will find that types are never implicitly casted to `Boolean`.

References:

- [11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)
- [9.3 ToNumber](https://es5.github.io/#x9.3)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake - I obviously misunderstood the question. +1 for an *actual* answer. ;)

Comment: Small question. Though equality operator itself doesn't do any conversion, ToNumber does. Since equality operator uses ToNumber function, wouldn't technically this mean that equality operator converts ?

Comment: @AlexanderK. it converts passed values implicitly to some general type, that's right.

Comment: In that case, it seems the original statement by Flanagan is not technically correct, isn't it? What I mean is, while equality operator itself doesn't do any conversion, it uses functions as a part of its algorithm that do conversion.

Comment: @AlexanderK. it is correct, during that conversion a particular operand value is never casted to a boolean. He did not say that during `==` operator application no conversions are performed, but said that no conversions to booleans are performed.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I keep forgetting that he is being specific about conversion to booleans, not in general.